# Perl passing 3D hash indexes as strings

Tags: json, perl, hash, hashmap

I am performing JSON parsing and the final hash which I get of all the JSON file .. the function being called is passing index entries which I need to print. If I try to put the variable as it is .. it dies with the error.
The commented out line is what I am trying to get ... The reason for using this function is to pass different values and get any kind of combination i need.

```
&Function('{value}{Agent}{macName}')


sub Function(){
    my $key = $_[0];
    my $URL = "www.xyz.com";
    my $json = get( $URL );
    my $decoded_json = decode_json( $json );

    for ( @{$decoded_json->{value}} ) {
       #print $_->{value}{Agent}{macName}."\n";
       print $_->$key."\n";

    }
}


Can't call method "{value}{Agent}{macName}" on unblessed reference at Json_Decoder.pl line 34.
```

How can I access this entry? print $_->{value}{Agent}{macName} ... by using '{value}{Agent}{macName}' argument of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver), it makes it possible to specify a "path" of hash keys as a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Diver qw{ Dive };

sub Function {
    my $key = shift;
    my $decoded_json = { value => { Agent => { macName => 'name' } } };
    my @path = split /\}\{/, $key;
    $path[-1] =~ s/\}$//;
    $path[0]  =~ s/^\{//;

    print Dive($decoded_json, @path), "\n";
}


Function('{value}{Agent}{macName}');
```

Also notice that you don't need the `&` to call the function, and that the empty prototype `()` is wrong in your code (but ignored as the function is called "before" it's declared). See [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub) for details.